# org.junit.runner does not exist

Tags: java, maven, junit

I am trying to build a Java Spring project with JUnit tests and Maven.

My `pom.xml` has

```
<parent>
    <groupId>beatechs</groupId>
    <artifactId>beatechs</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<groupId>beatechs.dao</groupId>
<artifactId>beatechs.dao</artifactId>
<name>beatechs.dao</name>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.4.24.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--        <dependency>-->
    <!--            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>-->
    <!--            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>-->
    <!--            <version>2.3.1</version>-->
    <!--        </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.46</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.springtestdbunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test-dbunit</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.19.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>beatechs.modelNew</groupId>
        <artifactId>beatechs.modelNew</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>beatechs</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and my test files are under src>test>Java>com.class.name.test>testclass.class

I do not understand why this error happens and I have tried to remove scope variable as well. My project structure displays Maven:junit:4.12 so I cannot understand why it can't find the required dependency

Comment: what are you trying with maven? mvn install? mvn test? can you post please your whole pom.xml file contents?

Comment: @WilliamAndrésBernal I did update the info, also maven test and maven install works fine but compiling project doesnt

Comment: What is the maven configuration of your parent project?

Comment: Is the path really `src/test/Java/com.class.name.test/testclass.class`? Since the folder hierarchy represents the package hierarchy the path for your test `*.java` files should rather look like `src/test/java/com/class/name/test/` (note the `.../java/...` with lowercase; doesn't matter on Windows but on *nix...).

Comment: Furthermore, `<packaging>jar` is the default, you don't have to declare it explicitely. The `<url>http://maven.apache.org` tells us that your project is under the hood of the Maven chapter of the Apache Software Foundation. It's most probably not, is it? You don't have to declare the `<build>...maven-compiler-plugin` just for the Java versions. [`<properties><maven.compiler.release>1.8`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#release) is sufficient. It recognizes this as property by itself.

Answer (score 0):

When you're new to Spring Boot then let [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) create your `pom.xml`. It will create a working `pom.xml`.